# Creating HTML Dynamic FORM using JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, dynamic

I'm trying to create a dynamic form using JS and PHP, I've done the PHP part, where the user selects how many rows he wants and the program generate that number of rows. The JS part is to display a HTML select box only if a checkbox is checked. I done that using the following function:

```
var checkBox = document.getElementById("box");
function repeatedCheck(){
  if(checkBox.checked==true){
  document.getElementById('sel').innerHTML="<select name='sel'>
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  .
  .
  //more options ..
  </select>";}
  else{
    document.getElementById('sel').innerHTML="";
  }
}
```

and this is the HTML part which generated by PHP program:

```
<table>
<?php
    for($i=1;$i<=$numOfRows;$i++){
           echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='box' name='repeated' onclick='repeatedCheck()'></td>";
           echo "<td id='sel'></td>";
           echo "</tr>";
       }
?>
</table>
```

The problem is, nothing shows up when the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

You are missing the input event, so your function does not run when user changes the checkbox state.

Additionally, I recommend you to have your `select` input already written in HTML instead of using `innerHTML`. Or at least create the element manually with `document.createElement()` if you need to change options dynamically.

Please let me know if you have any doubt.

```js
const checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');

function onChangeHandler(e){
  if (e.target.checked === true) {
    e.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = null;
  } else {
    e.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'></checkbox>
    <select name='select' style='display: none;'>
      <option value='1'>1</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <input class='checkbox' type='checkbox'></checkbox>
    <select name='select' style='display: none;'>
      <option value='1'>1</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank You, it works great now, but just one last thing for my understanding purposes, what does `.nextElementSibling` do? and why checkboxes are constant, will anything be different if it's var? and apologize if i disturbed you with too many questions.

Comment: @AhmedKena don't worry! We are here to help. `Element.nextElementSibling` gives you the next HTML element following your current one. So, calling it on `checkbox` will give you the `select` element, allowing you to show/hide it. For `const` vs. `var` I would refer you to [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/) article.